# play counts in YouTube API watchhistory?

Tags: youtube-api

Has anyone had any success in deriving play counts from the YT API's watchHistory?
Play counts don't seem to be included directly, so I thought I could count occurrences of a specific video in my history to get a personal view count. But it looks like whenever you watch a video again it just gets moved to the top of your history, there are no dupes. Any secrets here?

Comment: Looks like this isn't currently possible via the API ... not even the feed at the YT site displays the playcount for each vid in the watch history (whether or not that information is collected is another story, but it doesn't appear there's any way it is currently exposed).

Comment: That does seem to be the case. Just wanted to throw it out there to see if I as missing an obvious thing. Thanks.