# Youtube API Request for accessing video view count at given date?

Tags: api, video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I know that the Youtube Data API can be used to access the **total** viewCount of a video.

However, I would like to view the **previous** viewCount of a video based on a specific date and/or time. For example, video A currently has a viewCount of *500,000* at the *current date and time* but perhaps **a month ago** it had a viewCount of *400,000*. How would I access that previous value?

Is there any Youtube API method or alternative resource that would allow me to access the previous view count of a video/list of videos?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't believe this is possible - see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927178/play-counts-in-youtube-api-watchhistory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927178/play-counts-in-youtube-api-watchhistory) and [http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4324/track-daily-view-count-of-youtube-videos](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4324/track-daily-view-count-of-youtube-videos)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be possible in the YouTube Data API. However, you may have to look into the [YouTube Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/).

To query, you have to use the [`reports.query` API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reference/reports/query) along with the appropriate [Dimensions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/dims) and [Metrics](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets). For example, Dimensions would be [`month`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/dims#month) and Metrics would be [`views`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets#views).